# Opencart Admin Inaccessible

Tags: .htaccess, e-commerce, opencart

I required a module for my opencart store but that module required vqMod.

After installing vqMod and installing this module, my admin website is unreachable, first time this has happened.

I've checked .htaccess which seems okay.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Latest Opencart Version.

Comment: Check the error.log file to see if any errors are logged. Its under system/logs folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vqmod don't causes such issue.

Try renaming /vqmod/xml folder, if it works then identify which file in /vqmod/xml causinig the issue by disabling all files in /xml one by one.

Most probably it should be your third party module file which is doing some messy operation via vqmod.

Comment: The reason why it didn't work was because i download the regular vqmod not the one for opencart.